# Send PDF file from DocumentsDirectory to iBooks

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, ibooks

I'm trying to send a downloaded pdf file from DocumentsDirectory to iBooks, and save it there. The code I used is:

```
    let url = URL(string: "itms-books://device_path_to_pdf_file/index.pdf")
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
      UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    } else {
      print("iBooks not installed")
    }
```

On runtime, this code opens iBooks on device but doesn't show the pdf file there.
I'm running this code on Xcode 8.3-Beta and iOs 10.3 on device.

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: My first guess is that you should use [UIDocument​Interaction​Controller](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller)

Comment: Yes, but I'd rather prefer only to show a 'Open in iBooks' button than all those UIDocumentInteractionController related options.

Comment: Well I think you have no option. Since your app is sandboxed and so are it files. Thus iBooks can't access it.

Comment: Do you find the Solution ???  if yes the share this @RFG

Comment: No, as @rckoenes points, I've used UIDocumentInteractionController.